# How to determine next tabstop in VBA UserForm?

Tags: vba

I have a UserForm with some textbox entry fields on it that are enabled/disabled by a checkbox. When a checkbox is clicked to check it, I'd like to move the focus into the now-enabled textbox.

The textbox is the next control after the checkbox in the tab order, so it seems like using the tab order to find the appropriate textbox would be a good idea.

But... how can I find the next control in the tab order after a given control? Is there a method to do that, or do I have to enumerate *all* the controls and figure it out for myself?

Comment: Dude I deleted my answer because it is incomplete, but I know for a fact there is such a function on either the form or the control, I've used it. Try looking at the inteli-sense options when you type ActiveControl followed by the dot. Would post code sample but am out Christmas shopping with the missus right now :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier: I think you must be thinking of VB as opposed to VBA. There's no FindControl method, and nothing on either the UserForm object or the ActiveControl object that fits the bill.

Comment: PS. I have never been on a ranch :-)

Comment: Gary yes, I did think this was VB.Net, apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate that this comes under the heading of "enumerating all the controls" but it's pretty simple and I attach the code for completeness:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.TabIndex = Me.ActiveControl.TabIndex + 1 Then
            ctl.SetFocus
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something pretty much like this - although note that not every type of control has a TabIndex property (e.g. Picture), so you need to guard against that.

Comment: If control is within a frame, instead of `Me.ActiveControl` you need to use `Me.MyFrameName.ActiveControl`, else VBA will treat the frame as an active control.

Answer (score 1):

As a different way of looking at this.

Can you not rather use the textbox you want focussed, and set that name in the checkbox.tag

then in you vba code use

```
DoCmd.GoToControl CheckBox.Tag
```

Where the *CheckBox.Tag* is the *Textbox.Name*?

EDIT:

OK, I found this

```
SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

at [VBA code for moving to next control? It must be eeeasy](http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/showflat.php?Board=83&Number=1721504)

Comment: Thanks. I could do, but I wanted to avoid putting the name of the control anywhere, because I want to be able to copy-and-paste these controls over and over - and I don't want to have to constantly update the name in the tag (or anywhere else).

Comment: No offence, but there is a more robust option than using send keys, send keys quite brittle in an environment where user can switch focus to another app before sendkeys fires.

Comment: Yeah, if I was going to go down that route, I'd at least use SendMessage to make sure that the message went to the right place. But, while this would no doubt work, I'll hang fire for a bit in the hope of getting a "better" answer. Actually, as things stand, I still lean towards enumerating all the controls and figuring out the next one myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with

```
SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

With a little experimentation I found this works

```
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
```

One caveat...if you're in the VBE stepping through the code, and watching it on the form, SendKeys is executed is executed in the code.  Confused the heck out of me at first why my code started to look odd, e.g. extra spacing and extra lines!

Comment: Yeah, while this would work OK 90% of the time (if running on my machine, and if I was prepared to keep my hands off the keyboard, etc.), it's not a solution I'd be prepared to roll out to lots of users.

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to the kind advice offered thus far, this issue shouldn't be addressed through programming when there's a way to address it within the userform itself.

Click on the userform itself, then right click and select "tab order". You can then move each element within the userform to whatever position you want without having to resort to complicated and unstable programming tricks.

Comment: This is ancient history now, but: I mentioned tab order in the question. I know how to set that. At the time, I was building a UI that extended/improved on the default behaviour, and was simply surprised that the tab order sequence wasn't easily discoverable via the API.

Comment: I was just providing some guidance for others who may have come upon this thread like I did, but who did not get a workable answer from the answers that were given.